# How to get the client app (not user) IP or domain with Laravel - Angular

Tags: php, angular, laravel, rest, http

I want to check if the incoming requests come from few allowed domains (my own angular clients), so I could secure my app even if the token is sent in each request.

I've tried (from my online app) to access the ip address  with $request->getClientIp(); but I always get the same ip: 172.17.0.1 when I acces from postman and the angular client.

I've also tried to get the origin and User-Agent, but it's very easy to change the header from postman, so it would not be secure.

Is there any way to know the client app domain or ip (which is secure over https) from the Laravel restful app?

Edit:

I'm serving my app over Dokku

Comment: Do you have any load balancer/firewalls/cache in front of your web server? You may need to use the [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header, but only when the immediate connection is from infrastructure you trust.

Comment: As its seeing the docker bridge, you'll want to forward the IP then use REAL_IP or X-Forwarded-For, but with all reverse proxies you can no longer trust the origin as all but REMOTE_ADDR can be forged.

Comment: @Scuzzy. thank you. I'm using Dokku to serve my app. And I think using headers is not an option because it's so easy to change the headers value in the request. I'm looking for something that check the domain from DNS or something secure.

Comment: To my understanding angular client and api is on different domain and you would like to make sure api request is made to using this angular clients only , you configure api server with Cross Origin Request and allow request from angular clients ....

Comment: Thank you. I've done, but I can still acces the api using postman.

Comment: @judasane You can trust the X-Forwarded-For header if you know it was set by internal infrastructure. at which point you can trust the clsoest IP received by the forwarding server.